# Linking an SDK into a project with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, sdk

so super newbie question, as I've not much experience using outside SDKs -

I'm trying to include the NVidia FleX SDK into my project, and I'm getting linker errors when calling any of the library's functions.

In my Project Settings, I have in my Include Directories a path pointing to the header file that I need. Under Library Directories, I have a path pointing to the library that it uses.

There's also a bin folder I'm not too sure what to do with - it holds the dll that the library uses. I've used the FBX SDK before, which didn't have a bin folder or DLL that needed to be linked.

If I use

```
#pragma comment( lib, "flexDebug_x86" )
```

The linker doesn't complain, but running it produces an error saying that it can't find the DLL. I've tried putting the path to the DLL under Library Directories - not sure where that should actually go.

Thank you!

Comment: Is the folder containing the dll in the system PATH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to copy the DLLs to your VS Project Path.
Or you put the path to the DLL into Computer Environment Path.